# Difference between Fragmentation and Budding

Tags: reproduction, asexual-reproduction

I have heard about two terms stating similar things - **Fission** and **Fragmentation** . I know Amoeba undergoes fission and Fragmentation is done by spirogyra. So what's the main difference between them?

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Could you add context to your question? Are you talking about cellular processes?

Comment: Yes, i am talking about asexual reproduction.

Comment: As far as I remember yeast undergoes budding (in fact even hydra does). Have never heard of amoebae budding. Wasn't the amoeba thing plain old binary fission?

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. See the edit